# I have a text file which contains sets , how do i read them as sets when i load on python?

Tags: python, list, set

My text file looks like this

{} /n {}/n

When I use readline, I get it as a list , like ['{}' , '{}]

how do I remove the string and read them as sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code work for you.

```py
with open('yourfile.txt','r') as file:
    data = file.read().splitlines()
    data = [set(a[1:-1].split(',')) for a in data]
print(data)
```

You can use `eval` also here, But using `eval` might be [`dangerous`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice#:%7E:text=An%20application%20that%27s%20fundamentally%20mis-designed%20is%20fundamentally%20mis-designed.,to%20exist.%20eval%20isn%27t%20insecure.%20Applications%20are%20insecure.).

```py
with open('yourfile.txt','r') as file:
    data = file.read().splitlines()
    data = [eval(a) for a in data]
print(data)
```

Comment: the first code doesnt work as it messes up the format